# Integral of the square of the spectral density in a quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, unitarity, density-of-states

The quantity of interest is
$$
\int_0^\infty dE \, \rho(E)^2
$$
where $\rho(E)$ is the spectral density in a Quantum Field Theory. I am wondering whether

1. it has any physical meaning, and
2. it can be proved to be finite.

Considerations for a specific case are well-accepted as a starting point. I was thinking of some kind of bound from unitarity or LSZ formula, but until now I could not derive any useful formula.

A physically relevant example I was considering is the differential cross
section for the process $e^+ e^- \rightarrow \text{hadrons}$ that, at leading order in the electromagnetic coupling, is proportional to the QCD spectral density evaluated between hadronic electro-magnetic currents, see e.g. the introduction to [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.99.094508). For this case, the integral of the spectral density would then be defined, but what about the integral of its square?

It is also known that, in general, the spectral densities appearing in lattice correlators grow asymptotically with the energy, so the above integral is not well-defined in general, unless a weight function $\omega$ (e.g. exponentially decreasing with $E$) is introduced in the integral. Considerations for the more generic computation of
$$
\int_0^\infty dE \, \omega(E) \rho(E)^2
$$
for different choices of $\omega$ are also encouraged.